# Could this be a security risk?

Tags: security, coldfusion

First this is on an intranet site, with only a few ip addresses allowed access. 
The exchange account allows access to all email addresses and we don't want our users to have the password. Is there a better way ?

A link on a page like this:

```
<a target="mainFrame" href="EmailAccess.cfm">Email</a>
```

Where mainFrame is an iframe, and EmailAccess.cfm is just this :

```
<script>
    window.location = "https://exchange.domain.com/exchange/?Cmd=contents&username=master&password=masterpassword";
</script>
```

I did notice opening a console in IE or chrome and scanning network traffic will show the username and password. Is there some way to encrypt or mask this  ?

Comment: cfhttp comes to mind.